# Probability of collision between two particles (Statistical Mechanics)

Tags: energy, statistical-mechanics, collision, density

I'm pretty new to statistical mechanics. While reading an introductory book ("Fisica - Meccanica e termodinamica", translated "Physics - Mechanics and Thermodynamics" by C. Mencucci and V. Silvestrini, it's an italian book). I've stumbled on the section talking about the velocity distribution function (chapter 17, pages 583 - 584 - 585). Now the book introduces three functions:

$n(\vec{r}) = {\rho (\vec{r}) \over m}$ which is the particles density. $\rho (\vec{r})$, function of position $\vec{r}$, is the density, $m$ is the mass of a particle of an ideal gas.

$dN(\vec{r}) = n(\vec{r}) dV$ which is the number of particles inside the volume element

$P(\vec{r}) = {n(\vec{r}) \over N}$ which is the particle space distribution function, that is said to satisfy the property for which:

$\iiint P(\vec{r}) dV = {1 \over N} \iiint n(\vec{r}) dV = {1 \over N} \iiint dN(\vec{r}) = 1$

Where $N$ is the total number of particle in $dV$. Now these functions can be generalized to the velocity distribution context, thus:

$N(\vec{v}) = n(\vec{v}) dV$

$P(\vec{v}) = {n(\vec{v}) \over N}$

Now the first question: how do I physically interpret this functions? Should I even try to physically interpret them or should I just stick with the mathematics instead?

Later the author continues and infers that the function $P(\vec{v})$, if there are no outer stresses (if the velocity distribution is isotropic) could be defined to be only a function of $v^2$ thus a function of $K$ (kinetic energy). Henceforth, from there on, the author uses $P = P(K)$.

The following section is the most problematic to me: imagine two particles, whose initial energies are $K_1$ and $K_2$, colliding with each other, with resulting energies $K_1'$ and $K_2'$. The probability for this to happen is said to be proportional to $P(K_1)P(K_2)$ with proportionality constant $C$:

$p = CP(K_1)P(K_2)$

my question is why? I tried to figure it out by substituting $P(K)$ with ${n(\vec{v}) \over N}$. $dN(\vec{v}) = n(\vec{r}) dV$ represents - as it has been explained - all the particles in $dV$ with velocities between $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{v} + d\vec{v}$, therefore I could say that, since, for a collision to happen, the particles need to have a velocity with a direction **almost** towards the impact point (considering the particle not a point but a sphere with non-zero radius), thus between a certain velocity $\vec{v}$ and a certain other velocity $\vec{v} + d\vec{v}$, and since $N(\vec{v})$ represents all the possible velocities configurations (or at least I think so as $N$, in the case of $n(\vec{r})$, represented the number of particles in $dV$), $P(\vec{v}) dV$ can be thought as some kind of probability. But even if my reasoning is correct, which it seems unluky, where is the $dV$ factor? Is $P(\vec{v}) = P(v) = P(K)$? Why is there the need for the $C$ constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $\iiint P(\vec{r}) dV = {1 \over N} \iiint n(\vec{r}) dV = {1 \over N} \iiint dN(\vec{r}) = 1$

> Where $N$ is the total number of particle in $dV$. Now these functions can be generalized to the velocity distribution context, thus:

> $N(\vec{v}) = n(\vec{v}) dV$

Here you are changing from a number density $n(\vec r)$ that changes in space to a number density $"n"(\vec v)$ that changes in velocity space. In the latter function, I put the "n" in quotes, since it is clearly a different function than the first n function. This kind of bad notation turns out to be a running theme in much of physics.

But you are using the same symbol for both, which can cause some confusion. The functional form of $n(\vec r)$ and the functional form of $n(\vec v)$ are not the same, so it is confusing to use the same symbol for the function (since the only differentiator is the letter you chose to denote the function argument, which is just a dummy variable).

> $P(\vec{v}) = {n(\vec{v}) \over N}$

Same here. This is now a probability that the particle has velocity $v$, which is a different function than, say, the spatial probability.

> Now the first question: how do I physically interpret this functions?

You are likely leading towards the interpretation that
$$
P(\vec v)d^3v
$$
is the probability that a particle has velocity in the range $d^3v$ about $\vec v$. For example, at a fixed temperature T, a classical gas of particles would have
$$
P(\vec v) = Ae^{-\frac{mv^2}{2T}}\;,
$$
where $A$ is chosen such that the integral over all velocities is 1.

> Should I even try to physically interpret them or should I just stick with the mathematics instead?

Yes, both. The physical interpretation is as stated above. But also stick with the mathematics.

> Later the author continues and infers that the function $P(\vec{v})$, if there are no outer stresses (if the velocity distribution is isotropic) could be defined to be only a function of $v^2$ thus a function of $K$ (kinetic energy). Henceforth, from there on, the author uses $P = P(K)$.

The author is performing a common abuse of notation. The functional form of
$P(K)$ is not the same as the functional form of $P(v)$ but the author is using the same letter to denote the function because of some strange desire to always denote a probability density with the letter $P$.

If we don't force ourselves to (confusingly) use the same letter, instead we would write
$$
1 = \iiint d^3v P(v) = 4\pi \int dv v^2 P(v) = 4\pi \int dK \frac{dv}{dK} v^2(K) P(v(K))\equiv \int dK \tilde P(K)\;,
$$
and then we would read off the probability density in kinetic energy $\tilde P(K)$ (where I use $\tilde P$ instead of just plain $P$ to avoid confusion) as:
$$
\tilde P(K) = \frac{4\pi}{mv(K)} v^2(K)P(v(K)) = \frac{4\pi}{m\sqrt{2K/m}}\frac{2K}{m}P(\sqrt{\frac{2K}{m}})
$$

> The following section is the most problematic to me: imagine two particles, whose initial energies are $K_1$ and $K_2$, colliding with each other, with resulting energies $K_1'$ and $K_2'$. The probability for this to happen is said to be proportional to $P(K_1)P(K_2)$ with proportionality constant $C$:

> $p = CP(K_1)P(K_2)$

> my question is why?

At this point, your $P(K)$ denotes the probability density that the particle has kinetic energy $K$. The probability you are interested in is roughly the probability that a particle with energy close to $K_1$ gets close (in space) to a particle with energy close to $K_2$. In general, this is some complicated function:
$$
P_2(\vec r, K; \vec r', K')\;,
$$
but as above, we assume we can ignore spatial variation (i.e., there is no dependence on $r$ and $r'$), and then we further go to the so-called "mean field" or "molecular chaos" approximation in which we can treat the particles as independent. This means that the probability of "A and B" $P_2(\vec r_A, K_A; \vec r_B,K_B)$ can be factored into *the unconditional probabilities that "A"* multiplied by *the unconditional probability that "B"*. I.e.,
$$
P_2(\vec r, K ; \vec r', K') \to CP(K)P(K')\;,
$$
where $C$ is whatever constant arrises from all the spatial integrals, etc, i.e., just whatever it needs to be to make the total integral equal to 1. Of course, if you have already normalized the $P(K)$ correctly, the $C$ might already be equal to 1, but it's not clear without more context.

> I tried to figure it out by substituting $P(K)$ with ${n(\vec{v}) \over N}$.

Use the example above for the Boltzmann distribution to understand how to make the change of variables correctly. You basically use $P(K) = \frac{dv}{dK}P(v(K))$ with the understanding that the two $P$s are actually different functions on each side of the equation. (Bad confusing physicist notation).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation: it's very clear! Just one more question, in the example above, where you show how to perform a change of variabile from $P(v)$ to $ P(K)$, I can't quite catch where the factor of $4 \pi$ arises from.

Comment: It may or may not arise depending on your starting definition for $P(v)$. But, in my case, I wrote $P(v)$ as the density that gets multiplied against $d^3v$, the volume element in velocity space. This volume element is equal to $d^2\Omega_v dvv^2$, where $v$ is the magnitude of the velocity. (This is just like how in real space $d^3r = d^2\Omega dr r^2$, where $r$ is the distance from the origin.)

Comment: So, because my $P(v)$ only depends on the magnitude of the velocity, I can do the solid angle ($d^2\Omega$) integral. I.e., $\iiint d^2\Omega dv v^2 P(v) = 4\pi\int dv v^2 P(v)$. You can start to see why the value should be $4\pi$ in three dimensional space by comparing to the surface area of a sphere, which is $4\pi r^2$.

Comment: Yes, I see how it works now, but, since I'm not very practical with this method of integration. Why is it necessary to place boundaries for the surface integrals of the solid angle?
I assume you did something like this: $\iiint P(v) d^3 v = \iint_S \sin \theta d \theta d \phi \int P(v) v^2 dv$. Since the starting volume integral is indefinite, or "over the entire space" - as it is said in the book -, where does $S$ come from sand why does $S$ correspond to the parameterized surface of an entire sphere? Couldn't it be, for instance, just a particular sector of the surface of the sphere?

Comment: There are boundaries on the angular integrals because we only want to cover all of space once, not more than once. For example, in 2D you would only want the angular variable to range from 0 to 2$\pi$ radians since that is a complete circle. Similarly, in 3D, the solid angle varies from 0 to 4$\pi$ steradians when we integrate over all space.